# ODBC call failed, multipart identifier 'dbo.Contenders.PersonID' could not be bound

Tags: sql, azure, odbc, cloud, ms-access-2016

I am running this code on access my tables have been linked and migrated to the cloud, this code works fine when it was not on cloud. I have taken two queries and done a left join on one of them.

I cannot figure out where the error is, I have checked for typos, the error is telling me that Contenders.PersonID is not bound however contenders is my table name which is working fine in the contender query.

The query I am getting an error is:

> ODBC call failed, multipart identifier 'dbo.Contenders.PersonID' could not be bound

```
SELECT Query11.First_name, Query11.Last_name, Query11.[Award Name], 
       Query11.Affiliation, Query11.Recipient_Award_Comments, 
       Query11.Recipient_Date, Query22.First_name, Query22.Last_name, 
       Query22.[Award Name], Query22.Contender_Date_Assigned, 
       Query22.Award_Contender_Comments, Query11.PersonID
FROM Query11 LEFT JOIN 
     Query22 
     ON Query11.PersonID = Query22.PersonID;
```

The contender query is

```
SELECT Awards.[Award Name], People.First_name, People.Last_name, 
       Contenders.Contender_Date_Assigned, 
       Contenders.Award_Contender_Comments, People.PersonID
FROM people, contenders, awards
WHERE Awards.AwardID = Contenders.AwardID AND 
      People.PersonID = Contenders.PersonID;
```

Also when I make the 'LEFT JOIN' to 'INNER JOIN' the query is working fine.

Comment: I can't find any relation of error message with first query.

Comment: Is there any tables with name of `Query11` or `Query22` ??

Comment: No the table names our Contenders and Recipients, I have created two queries using the table names and I am doing a join on those queries.

This one is query 11 (using recipient table, people table and wards table )

SELECT People.First_name, People.Last_name, Awards.[Award Name], Recipients.Affiliation, Recipients.Recipient_Award_Comments, Recipients.Recipient_Date, People.PersonID
FROM People INNER JOIN (Awards INNER JOIN Recipients ON Awards.AwardID = Recipients.AwardID) ON People.PersonID = Recipients.PersonID;

Comment: It would be easy to follow if you include your actual `Query` instead of this.

Comment: the problem is that I have more than 7 tales to join ( left join and inner join ) therefore combining multiple small queries is working perfectly on access but when I deploy it on the cloud ( azure ) I am getting a multi part error in something which does not exist in the query I am running

Comment: if these queries are working on access there is something on the cloud which is creating these queries not to be bound and I am unable to figure out what, it would be great if you could help me.

Comment: Post your actual query.

Comment: SELECT People.First_name, People.Last_name, Recipients.Affiliation, Recipients.Recipient_Award_Comments, Recipients.Recipient_Date, People.PersonID, Awards.[Award Name], Awards.AwardID
FROM Awards INNER JOIN (People INNER JOIN Recipients ON People.PersonID = Recipients.PersonID) ON Awards.AwardID = Recipients.AwardID;

this is query 11, I have saved it as query 11.

Comment: SELECT People.First_name, People.Last_name, Contenders.Contender_Date_Assigned, Contenders.Award_Contender_Comments, People.PersonID, Awards.[Award Name]
FROM Awards INNER JOIN (People INNER JOIN Contenders ON People.PersonID = Contenders.PersonID) ON Awards.AwardID = Contenders.AwardID;
this is query 22 I have saved it as query 22

Comment: SELECT Query11.First_name, Query11.Last_name, Query11.[Award Name], Query11.Affiliation, Query11.Recipient_Award_Comments, Query11.Recipient_Date, Query22.First_name, Query22.Last_name, Query22.[Award Name], Query22.Contender_Date_Assigned, Query22.Award_Contender_Comments, Query11.PersonID
FROM Query11 LEFT JOIN Query22 ON Query11.PersonID = Query22.PersonID;
 this is the combination of two queries on which I am getting an error

Comment: this is working fine on access but when i put it on cloud I am getting odbc call failed [microsoft sql server native client] [sql server] multipart identifier 'ms1awardid' could not be bound (#4104) [microsoft sql server native client] [sql server] mulitpart identifier 'dbo.Contenders.AwardID' could not be bound (#4104) [microsoft sql server native client] [sql server] mulitpart identifier 'dbo.Contenders.PersonID' could not be bound

Comment: None of can help you with this information that you have provided & your edits are not in right place it should be in your question. So, i would suggest ask another question with your actual query where it worked & where it is not worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634018/odbc-call-failed-microsoft-sql-server-native-client-11-0-sql-server-the-mu