# odbc call failed [microsoft] [sql server native client 11.0] [sql server] the multipart identifier coild not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, ms-access-2016

I have two queries, which use tables linked using an ODBC database, both are simple enough and individually work fine.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    People.First_name, People.Last_name, Awards.[Award Name], 
    Recipients.Affiliation, Recipients.Recipient_Award_Comments, 
    Recipients.Recipient_Date, People.PersonID 
FROM
    People 
INNER JOIN 
    (Awards 
INNER JOIN 
    Recipients ON Awards.AwardID = Recipients.AwardID) ON People.PersonID = Recipients.PersonID;
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    Awards.[Award Name], People.First_name, People.Last_name, 
    Contenders.Contender_Date_Assigned, 
    Contenders.Award_Contender_Comments, People.PersonID
FROM 
    people, contenders, awards
WHERE 
    Awards.AwardID = Contenders.AwardID 
    AND People.PersonID = Contenders.PersonID;
```

I tried using a left join on these queries ( which works fine on access , but on migrating the data to SQL Server) I am getting this error:

> odbc call failed [microsoft] [sql server native client 11.0] [sql server] the multipart identifier 'Contenders.PersonID' could not be bound, 'Contenders.AwardID' could not be bound and 'Awards.AwardID' could not be bound.

On doing an inner join it works fine but it isn't what I want.

**Query r+c**

```
SELECT 
    Query1.First_name, Query1.Last_name, Query1.[Award Name], 
    Query1.Affiliation, Query1.Recipient_Award_Comments, 
    Query1.Recipient_Date, Query2.First_name, Query2.Last_name, 
    Query2.[Award Name], Query2.Contender_Date_Assigned, 
    Query2.Award_Contender_Comments, Query1.PersonID
FROM
    Query1 
LEFT JOIN 
    Query2 ON Query1.PersonID = Query2.PersonID;
```

Comment: Never use Old style of `JOIN` with `WHERE` clause use always explicit `JOIN` Syntax.

Comment: Why have you added the Azure tag?  Nowhere in your question you mentioned Azure.

Comment: The error says **sql server native client**, but your tags claim this is MS Access 2016 - which one is it really??

Comment: @csharp, I have actually migrated it on sql azure.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly

Comment: @marc_s I have migrated the data from ms-access to the cloud and sql native client is probably a connection driver which I installed in my pc to link my front end ( forms and reports ) to the data on the cloud

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
with Query11 as
(
   <Query11 goes here>
), Query22 as
(
   <Query22 goes here>
)

select  q1.First_name, q1.Last_name, Query1.[Award Name], 
        q1.Affiliation, q1.Recipient_Award_Comments, 
        q1.Recipient_Date, q2.First_name, Query2.Last_name, 
        q2.[Award Name], q2.Contender_Date_Assigned, 
        q2.Award_Contender_Comments, q1.PersonID
from Query11 q1 left join
     Query22 q2
     on q2.PersonID = q1.PersonID;
```

I would rewrite the `Query11` as :

```
SELECT p.First_name, p.Last_name, a.[Award Name], 
       r.Affiliation, r.Recipient_Award_Comments, 
       r.Recipient_Date, p.PersonID 
FROM People p INNER JOIN 
     Recipients r
     ON p.PersonID = r.PersonID INNER JOIN
     Awards a
     ON a.AwardID = r.AwardID;
```

Comment: on rewriting I am getting a syntax error ( missing operator ) in query expression p.PersonID = r.PersonID INNER JOIN
     Awards a
     ON a.AwardID = r.AwardID

Comment: I am getting an invalid statement error in the first query you have written , with Query11 as
(
   <Query11 goes here>..................

Comment: on rewriting the query 11 ( I added appropriate parenthesis) and running my original query 'r+c' again I am getting the same error (odbc call failed)..